# I'm having problems with Angular data transfer with API

Tags: angular, datatable, datasource

In Angular, I cannot fill the data from the api to the table, I think there is an error in the datasource section, but I could not find it, when I follow from the console, I get the data from the api in a healthy way, but when I come to the transfer to the table, the table also appears empty.

```
export class List_University {
Id:string;
UniversityName :string;
UniversityDescription :string;
CreatedDate :Date;
UpdateDate :Date;
```

my service part where I meet the object

```
async read(page: number = 0, size: number = 5, successCallBack?: () => void, errorCallBack?: (errorMessage: string) => void): Promise<{ totalCount: number; university: List_University[] }> {
try {
  const observable = this.httpClientService.get<{ totalCount: number; university: List_University[] }>({
    controller: "university",
    queryString: `page=${page}&size=${size}`
  });

  const data = await firstValueFrom(observable);

  if (successCallBack) {
    successCallBack();
  }
  return data;

} catch (errorResponse) {
  if (errorCallBack) {
    errorCallBack(errorResponse.message);
  }
  throw errorResponse;
}
```

my list component where I use the related service

```
    export class ListComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private universityService: UniversityService, private alertifyService: AlertifyService) {
    super(spinner)
  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['UniversityName', 'UniversityDescription', 'CreatedDate', 'UpdateDate', 'Delete'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<List_University> = null;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  async getUniversities() {
    this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.BallScaleMultiple);
    const allUniversity: { totalCount: number; university: List_University[] } = await this.universityService.read(
      this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageIndex : 0, this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageSize : 5,
      () => this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallScaleMultiple),
      errorMessage => this.alertifyService.message(errorMessage,
        {
          dismissOther: true,
          messageType: MessageType.Error,
          position: Position.TopRight
        }));
        console.log('Tüm üniversiteler:', allUniversity);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_University>(allUniversity.university);
        this.paginator.length = allUniversity.totalCount;
        
        console.log('ikinci üniversiteler:', this.dataSource.data);
        
        
      }
      async ngOnInit() {
        await this.getUniversities();
      }
      async pageChanged() {
        await this.getUniversities();
      }
```

my html codes that I meet

```
 <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="UniversityName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UniversityName </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.UniversityName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="UniversityDescription">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UniversityDescription </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.UniversityDescription}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="CreatedDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CreatedDate </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CreatedDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="UpdateDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UpdateDate </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.UpdateDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Delete">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><img src="src\assets\delete.png"> Sil </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator (page)="pageChanged()" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons
    aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

[image]
I tried to throw the relevant codes appropriately, but I think I had a problem with the last line, I apologize, please share your valuable ideas and help me solve the error

Comment: can you share stackblitz ? since you have said API works fine put static data there

Comment: @KrunalJethva hello thank you for your reply, the link you requested 
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/mehmetaybey/QuizBankFront

Comment: Don't know it it's related, but you are accessing a ViewChild paginator inside the OnInit method, but ViewChild properties are only initialized on the AfterViewInit method

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier I tried but there was no solution :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the type of your data is incorrect and the template too.

1. Check the type of your class & Name of variable :

:

```
 export class List_University {
    Id:string;
    UniversityName :string;
    UniversityDescription :string;
    CreatedDate :Date;
    UpdateDate :Date;
  }
```

But in your screenshot, all properties are in camelCase from uni array.

Exemple:

```
universityName
unisersityDescription
createDate
updateDate
```

2. Using correct properties in the template

So in the template, you've declared:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="UniversityName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UniversityName </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.UniversityName}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

instead of

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="UniversityName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UniversityName </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.universityName}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

3. DataSource

And this line is incorrect :

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_University>(allUniversity.university);


    console.log('Tüm üniversiteler:', allUniversity);
```

Your log returns an object that contains **totalCount** and **uni** properties based on your screenshot, however you have declared allUniversity.university instead of allUniversity.uni.

You need to verify the response of your data, university property does not exist here:

```
{
 totalCount: 22,
 uni: [
  {id: 'aa', universityName: 'xxx', universityDescription: 'oo', ...},
  .... 
 ]
}
```

So you should make changes like that:

```
   const allUniversity: { totalCount: number; uni: List_University[] } = await this.universityService.read(
      this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageIndex : 0, this.paginator ? this.paginator.pageSize : 5,
      () => this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallScaleMultiple),
      errorMessage => this.alertifyService.message(errorMessage,
        {
          dismissOther: true,
          messageType: MessageType.Error,
          position: Position.TopRight
        }));
        console.log('Tüm üniversiteler:', allUniversity);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<List_University>(allUniversity.uni);
        this.paginator.length = allUniversity.totalCount;
        
        console.log('ikinci üniversiteler:', this.dataSource.data);
        
      }
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, when I added the relevant line I couldn't understand exactly what to expect, I'm new yet, I apologize

Comment: @Mehmet I juste updated my message. I think this will help you. It's works perfectly for me on test branch: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/mybugatti/QuizBankFront